# Importing and exporting the same element in PBC Library

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography

I'm a freshman to the PBC library. Now I have been being troubled with an odd problem which may be inside the library. That is, I cannot get an element itself with `element_from_bytes` from a bytes buffer which contains what I can get from the same element by `element_to_bytes`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <pbc/pbc.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  pairing_t pairing;
  FILE * file_data;
  unsigned char  buffer[1024];

  element_t e_G1;
  element_t e_G2;
  element_t e_GT;

  file_data = fopen("a.param", "rb");
  fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 1024, file_data);
  fclose(file_data);

  pairing_init_set_buf(pairing, buffer, 1024);

  pbc_random_set_file("/dev/urandom");

  element_init_G1(e_G1, pairing);
  element_init_G1(e_G2, pairing);
  element_init_GT(e_GT, pairing);

  element_random(e_G1);
  element_set(e_G2, e_G1);
  element_to_bytes(buffer, e_G1);
  element_from_bytes(e_G1, buffer);

  element_random(e_GT);
  element_to_bytes(buffer, e_GT);
  element_from_bytes(e_G1, buffer);

  element_printf("%B\n\
-----------------------------------------------\n%B\n\
-----------------------------------------------\n%B\n\
-----------------------------------------------\n%d\n\n",
                                                    e_G1,  
                                                    e_G2, 
                                                    e_GT, 
                                      element_is0(e_G1));
  return 0;
}
```

and what I get is here:

```
O
-----------------------------------------------
[8021850106505818502224442208928855004938939439678477694892641266967078361854270086432817366784978788884366884435675935152080578989270423349970705389370184, 2207681943758336273091052288242865038000441662104450034566345617121836958254088636097196267885483421854988093922900438274171762807585817974640138776324140]
-----------------------------------------------
[7792468460669792001225496496730815439034004409253407100165449658873999461802182391001847130721570852427585544191514409272430371044941965363904582878220488, 7159904157534661386227436046498970442391860436703403633250884233122825330691897165426605400567350719613160801169558771636512036955882768503813467951267422]
-----------------------------------------------
1
```

By the way, I'm using ubuntu 14.04 x64 and the version of pbc library is 0.5.14 and the file "a.param" is copied from the uncompressed PBC folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e_G1` was initialized as an element of group G1, but `buffer` contains an element of GT in serialized form. Those are incompatible, because they are in different groups with different sizes (extension fields and such).

If you initialize `e_G1` as an element of GT, then it will work:

```
element_random(e_GT);
element_to_bytes(buffer, e_GT);
element_init_GT(e_G1, pairing);
element_from_bytes(e_G1, buffer);
```